# Postfix and Sparkpost relay authentication failures

Tags: email, ssl, postfix, debian-stretch

Until recently I have had no problems with relays and forwards from Postfix through Sparkpost. Now I get authentication errors 530 5.7.1. The server is running Debian Stretch. The settings in Postfix main.cf are set as Sparkpost recommends.

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:SMTP_Injection:My_API_key
```

I have a mailbox, me@example.com that forwards to me@otheraddress.com. The message is delivered to me@example.com, but the mail log shows the following re the forward:

```
Dec 31 11:19:48 example postfix/smtp[19188]: 66AA357DD2: to=<me@otheraddress.com>, relay=smtp.sparkpostmail.com[52.26.175.191]:587, delay=0.38, delays=0.1/0.01/0.21/0.06, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host smtp.sparkpostmail.com[52.26.175.191] said: 530 5.7.1 Authorization required. Ref. https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/index#header-smtp-relay-endpoints (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Dec 31 11:19:48 example postfix/cleanup[19176]: EAB4957DD0: message-id=<20181231161948.EAB4957DD0@example.com>
Dec 31 11:19:49 example postfix/bounce[19189]: 66AA357DD2: sender non-delivery notification: EAB4957DD0
Dec 31 11:19:49 example postfix/qmgr[19147]: EAB4957DD0: from=<>, size=7611, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 31 11:19:49 example postfix/cleanup[19176]: 5777A57DD4: message-id=<20181231161949.5777A57DD4@example.com>
Dec 31 11:19:49 example postfix/bounce[19189]: 66AA357DD2: postmaster non-delivery notification: 5777A57DD4
```

I know the cert is working because I see no errors when I run

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:587 -starttls smtp
```

Output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=example.com
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGUjCCBTqgAwIBAgISBMCBEL46Fp5eG+d54abyrZxXMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
...
qFl1JeXAxKBW9nE9E5+ZuC+8SNF7LlqiN2bi5BMA1x0wiVXZk+fTAk3vRsTTr0CM
svdtByn4XF3UbPoBhnHv8IGXx0ZqXUWt141ZxkV2Mxaak2TyyK7IeVCqlWGIMC1z
pgOO7fdZMY1xC/TEDdxcMOyTf7C7Ih539kPoeM7wHdWNXsipbc3r6NWQ9440dCd1
yPXKfWzAPBhtqFF+T3SOFqQHr6twNRLT8ITu/PtiipxUAvO+wQrdLIrKzfpNeJW4
GXXXeV+crpGdvJa/EdYLZgx5O2DWX67VKerlVWTdcAGwvU3Jia8=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=example.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3733 bytes and written 335 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 3987DBFA6A51B83864E89C0E8E7C24EB9536355130F8ADE266033CEAE264B6B2
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: DA5D77AFF4C3B173144402101F9E59AE809C120679BDA9CE577D963148E5F405F205BB4898D3754BE6608863E9A7E5C0
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 16 25 d2 8c f4 00 d3 b2-de b8 23 a8 7d 9a 07 ed   .%........#.}...
    0010 - 45 2b e1 9d 15 94 6e 9a-b7 90 4b 8b cb c8 d9 98   E+....n...K.....
    0020 - 27 b6 31 ef 65 18 de db-05 e5 f1 90 1a a9 c2 dc   '.1.e...........
    0030 - 8b c0 2b 38 21 be fd ff-85 8c a2 7a af 86 bc 72   ..+8!......z...r
    0040 - 72 22 ed 67 04 3b 25 92-45 5d 83 ba 85 0e 27 c2   r".g.;%.E]....'.
    0050 - 71 01 ba ea f5 58 11 42-81 70 08 5d e2 22 d0 63   q....X.B.p.].".c
    0060 - 59 08 4c 53 c5 a8 27 37-b2 79 eb 88 55 81 c7 1d   Y.LS..'7.y..U...
    0070 - 0e 69 b2 05 b3 83 05 41-16 e5 18 ad 25 2a 80 2f   .i.....A....%*./
    0080 - 50 c5 d6 95 e8 d4 5a 19-68 7e a0 91 f0 21 ca d2   P.....Z.h~...!..
    0090 - b5 d9 56 58 15 7f d9 71-3a 71 ae 3f 47 a3 99 e2   ..VX...q:q.?G...
    00a0 - 7f 6e 1c 5a ea 85 bb 98-d6 bb a3 6e 40 7f 34 07   .n.Z.......n@.4.

    Start Time: 1546272800
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
250 SMTPUTF8
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The authorization problem is at the SMTP level, not at the TLS level. Thus checking if the certificate fits with `openssl s_client` is irrelevant - check the SMTP user and password instead.

Comment: You are correct. But it took some time to figure that out, and Sparkpost's error message 530 5.7.1 wasn't helpful. In fact, their suggested settings, only work in a limited set of circumstances, where all emails sent originate locally, and no user forward's email originating outside the local system.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I should have realized this at the beginning, and that would have saved hours of stumbling around in darkness. When an email arrives in a local mailbox and is forwarded, it retains the original sender address through the forward. IOW, an email from someone@elsewhere.com -> me@example.com that is forwarded to me@otheraddress.com arrives at smtp.sparkpostmail.com with its original sender address, someone@elsewhere.com. Sparkpost then bounces the email because elsewhere.com is not a sending domain it recognizes. The correct error message is 550 5.7.1, and should identify elsewhere.com as the configuration problem.

The solution I eventually arrived at is to configure postfix so it uses different transports and authentication credentials depending on the sender address. To do that you need to create two data files, or if you use postfix's mysql database, one data file and edit the postfix.transport table.

/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd includes local sending domains and Sparkpost login credentials:

```
@example.com  SMTP_Injection:<API key for example.com>
@example2.com  SMTP_Injection:<API key for example2.com>
```

/etc/postfix/relayhosts includes the local domains with the Sparkpost relayhost, and a catch-all for forwarded mail that passes through the server:

```
@example.com  [smtp.sparkpostmail.com]:587
@example2.com  [smtp.sparkpostmail.com]:587
*   smtps
```

Don't forget to postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd, and postmap /etc/postfix/relayhosts.

If using mysql, edit the postfix.transport table, adding [smtp.sparkpostmail.com]:587 in the transport field for each local domain that uses sparkpost. If you have local domains that don't use sparkpost, add "smtps" in the transport field. Create /etc/postfix/virtual_forward.cf to pull the same data from the transport table in the mysql db:

```
hosts = 127.0.0.1 (or localhost)
user = mysql-login
password = mysql-pw
dbname = postfix
query = SELECT transport FROM transport WHERE domain='%s' AND LENGTH(transport) > 0
```

Again, you must add a catch-all transport as the last record in the table:

```
*  smtps
```

As I understand it, smtps uses port 465 as defined in master.cf, and sends from the local server, not submission (smtpd) as defined in master.cf, which uses port 587 to send through Sparkpost.

To make all of this work, you need to add some settings to main.cf

```
#Unless the next line has no value, postfix cannot send from localhost
relayhost =
#Using the relayhosts file
sender_dependent_relayhosts_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relayhosts
#Using mysql
sender_dependent_relayhosts_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_forward.cf
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#Not sure the next 2 lines are absolutely necessary, but I assume they are because they relate to smtp, rather than smtpd (submission)
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

I hope this explanation saves others from having to spend hours slogging through the arcana of mailserverdom.